# None of the constructors found with - autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac

I have the following autofac-config:

```
public static void RegisterDI()
{
    var builder = GetBuilder();
    var container = builder.Build();

    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
}
public static ContainerBuilder GetBuilder()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
    builder.RegisterFilterProvider();

    var assemblies = BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Cast<Assembly>().Where(x => x.FullName.Contains("Soundyladder")).ToArray();

    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
        .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .InstancePerRequest();

    builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(assemblies);

    return builder;
}
```

My application consist of three layers: UI, Service, and DataAcces. Here is my UserRepository from the DataAccess-layer:

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
}
```

Here is my service from the the service layer:

```
public UserService(IUserRepository userRepository)
{
    this._userRepository = userRepository;
}
```

And here is my controller:

```
public UserController(IUserService userService)
{
    this._userService = userService;
}
```

Everytime I start the application, I get the following error:

> None of the constructors found with
>   'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type
>   'Soundyladder.Service.Services.UserService' can be invoked with the
>   available services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter
>   'Soundyladder.DataAccess.Repositories.IUserRepository userRepository'
>   of constructor 'Void
>   .ctor(Soundyladder.DataAccess.Repositories.IUserRepository)'.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of
>   the constructors found with
>   'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type
>   'Soundyladder.Service.Services.UserService' can be invoked with the
>   available services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter
>   'Soundyladder.DataAccess.Repositories.IUserRepository userRepository'
>   of constructor 'Void
>   .ctor(Soundyladder.DataAccess.Repositories.IUserRepository)'.

I have no idea why this happens. I have the same setup In this project that I have In my other projects. When I compare my other projects with this, I can't see any difference.

Comment: It looks like it wants you to make a constructor with a single parameter, ie: `public UserRepository(IUserRepository repo) { ... }`

Comment: @RonBeyer: In my Repository-class?

Comment: The answer to "can anyone help me" is "yes", but it's probably not actually the question you want to ask. As an editor I tend to trim it out - the best sorts of questions are specific, e.g. "why does <strange behaviour X> occur in <conditions>". That's much answerable than asking for "help", which is a bit broad and undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author)*.

I changed the autofac config. Now it's working:

```
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    builder.RegisterFilterProvider();

    var assemblies = BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Cast<Assembly>().Where(x => x.FullName.Contains("Soundyladder")).ToArray();
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .InstancePerRequest();

    return builder;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you only registering "Service" suffix types, and forgot about "Repository" suffix types.

```
.Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
```

Comment: But I have nothing to resolve in the repository-layer?

Comment: But `IUserService` is dependent on `IUserRepository`, so if you're trying to resolve IUserService, the `DependencyResolver` will try resolving all dependent classes before service you with desired IUserService instance.